# Ansible: Use variables in a playbook defined in different file (not the inventory file)

Tags: variables, ansible

I would like to use variables defined in a file (`hosts_vars`) in my playbook.
Here is the directory tree where the playbook is contained:

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── ansible.log
├── choco_deploy.yml
├── group_vars
│   └── win_clones.yml
├── hosts
├── hosts_vars
```

My host file:

```
[win_clones]
cl1 ansible_host='IP1'
cl3 ansible_host='IP2'
```

The `hosts_vars` file looks like this:

```
---
cl1:
  to_install:
   - soft1
   - soft2 46.0.1
  to_uninstall:
   - soft3 2.2.3
cl3:
  to_install:
  - soft4 2.2.3
  - soft5 6.9
  - sof6 6.9
  to_uninstall:
  - soft77
```

In my playbook I would like to refer for example to `host_vars/cl1/to_install/soft1` or to loop through all the variables of `host_vars/cl3/to_install/`. Something like:

```
tasks:
- name: Installing the packages ...
  win_chocolatey:
    name: "{{ package_id }}" # here to pass variables defined in host_vars
    state: present
```

How can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your playbook you can add `vars_files` to specify external variables files, like this:

```
---

hosts: all
remote_user: root   
vars_files:
    - path/to/hosts_vars

tasks:
    - name: my awesome task
      command: /bin/echo {{ myvar }}
```

And in your `hosts_vars`:

```
---

myvar: "foo"
myothervar: "bar"
```

See: [documentation for variable file separation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation)

Comment: Where should I place this? under tasks? How can I then refer to the variables? could you add some code...thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it. However my question is how to use those variable once I include them into the playbook. How do I refer to host_vars/cl1/to_install/soft1 or how do I loop through host_vars/cl3/to_install/?

Comment: @diegus you would use them as you would with any variable defined directly in the payload (I've updated my answer with usage example) For looping you would use `with_items`